# Change Y-axis in Google chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart

This is the code which I tried to show the chart with the help of Google chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <br/>

    <script>
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          },
          bars: 'Vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          hAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
          height: 400,
          colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

        var btns = document.getElementById('btn-group');

        btns.onclick = function (e) {

          if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
            options.hAxis.format = e.target.id === 'none' ? '' : e.target.id;
            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
          }
        }
      }
      </script>
```

This is the code I tried to show the bar chart. I just want to show dollar ($) sign in Y axis. Please help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <div id="chart_div"></div>
<br/>


<script>
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
      ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
      ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
      ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
      ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'Vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
      vAxis: {format: 'currency'},
      height: 400,
      colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    var btns = document.getElementById('btn-group');

    btns.onclick = function (e) {

      if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        options.hAxis.format = e.target.id === 'none' ? '' : e.target.id;
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wdf6wvpt/

Comment: Thanks @Ajay Raturi